# Android bluetooth settings show duplicate names for same bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, pairing

I am working with a firmware team that writes firmware on a QCC3056 Qualcomm chipset that supports earbuds and I develop an android application that supports the BLE earbud Bluetooth device. The earbuds also support google fast pair and this feature requires the BLE mac address to be rotated every 15 min.

So the issue I am seeing here is the android Bluetooth settings recognize two Bluetooth devices with the same name(one is classic and the other one is BLE). I can tell by the mac addresses that one belongs to classic and the other belongs to the BLE address. We are able to connect to the classic instance. However, we are unable to connect to the BLE instance. We would like just one name to show up and the user should be able to connect to it. The firmware team thinks this is expected behavior(two names showing up). As far as I know, from the android end, we don't have any control over the Bluetooth settings. So I wanted to understand if this behavior is expected. I have tested this scenario with SONY WF-1000XM3 which supports Google Fast Pair and I have noticed only one name showing up.

It would be great if anyone can suggest the best possible approach I can take here.

Comment: Your app is in Advertising mode or Scanning mode?

Comment: You will never be able to connect to a BLE device using the android bluetooth settings. BLE always requires an app

Comment: @SagarBalyan This has nothing to do with the app as android API provides two different ways to scan classic and ble devices. I am seeing this issue in the android settings screen. I am afraid the settings module code is scanning for both classic and ble. I wanted to understand how this problem can be addressed.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Thanks for the update. I am wondering how SONY was able to show up only one instance in the android settings. I also tested it with Beats Earbuds and only one name showed up. Our devices show up twice in the settings. Is this something the firmware team can fix or is there a workaround from the app end?

Comment: @AvinashParasurampuram I'm not sure. Maybe Sony only uses Bluetooth Classic in it's headphones? Bluetooth Classic is the technology used for streaming music and is even able to show the battery level of supported devices etc. If they enabled Bluetooth Classic as well as Bluetooth Low Energy in your device it will show up as two devices I believe

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I am pretty sure Sony uses BLE as that is required for Google Fast Pair to work.

Comment: I was looking for any documentation that proves that two devices will show up when BLE and Classic are used.

Comment: I don't have documentation for that, just my personal experience